# the rails server isn't getting started

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, windows-8.1, mysql2

it show some errors like

```
C:\Users\Vishnu\Sites\simple_cms>rails s

 E:/installations/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in
`require': 126: The specified module could not be found.   - E:/installations/Ru
by/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.0.0/mysql2-0.3.16/mysql2/mysql2.
so (LoadError)
        from E:/installations/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/my
sql2.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from E:/installations/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bu
ndler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
        from E:/installations/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bu
ndler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from E:/installations/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bu
ndler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from E:/installations/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bu
ndler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from E:/installations/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bu
ndler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from E:/installations/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bu
ndler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
        from E:/installations/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bu
ndler.rb:132:in `require'
        from C:/Users/Vishnu/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (
required)>'
        from E:/installations/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/r
ails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'
        from E:/installations/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/r
ails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server'
        from E:/installations/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/r
ails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
        from E:/installations/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/r
ails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
        from E:/installations/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/r
ails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
        from E:/installations/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/r
ails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Getting Rails to work with MySQL on a Windows machine is quite the headache. In the end, I either use SQLite on Windows or switch to my Linux partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some troubles and compiled a step by step instructions for anyone that encounter this problem:

To download:
(1) https://structure-svm-map.googlecode.com/files/svm-map-win.zip
(2) http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/

Step 0.
Uninstall mysql2 by entering the command in the command prompt:
gem uninstall mysql2

Step 1.
Copy gendef.exe from svm-map (1) to the MySql server directory and run the following the command in the command line:
gendef.exe libmysql.dll

Step 2.
Install MinGW (2) and install the basic repository
Remember where the MinGW is installed
Add "E:\MinGW\bin" (change depending where your application is installed) to PATH (environment variables)

Step 3.
Open a new instance of the command line and navigate to your MySql Server directory (mine's E:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6)
Run the following the command line:
dlltool -v --dllname libmysql.dll --def libmysql.def --output-lib libmysql.lib

Step 4.
Install mysql2 using rubygems in the command line with the following options (change depending where your MySQL Server is located):
gem install mysql2 --no-rdoc --no-ri -- '--withmysql-dir="E:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin" --with-mysql-lib="E:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib" --with-mysql-include="E:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\include"'

Step 5.
Copy over libmysql.dll from your MySQL server directory to "E:\Ruby200-x64\bin" (change depending on where the application is installed)

Step 6.
Try "rails server" in the command line to ensure if installation is done correctly

Answer (score 0):

Either you are missing the mysql2 gem in the Gemfile. Or the gem is not compiled. Try:

```
gem install mysql2
```

And run:

```
bundle
```

Before starting the server to ensure everything is tied.

Comment: I have installed the mysql2 gem already using "gem install mysql2 -- '--with-mysql-dir="C:\Program Files\MySQL\mysql server 5.6"'

Comment: There's something bad with the gem installation: check:
E:/installations/Ru
by/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.0.0/mysql2-0.3.16/mysql2/mysql2.
so this file is missing.

Comment: If I copy the file "libmysql.dll" it shows a long error

Comment: The file missing is mysql2.so

Comment: It might work. Looks like the file is either not existing or not working in the directory.

Comment: The "mysql2.so" file is there in that directory. I think it is not working.